# How to handle back button in GoRouter for mobile and web at the same time

Tags: flutter, web, mobile, gorouter

[According to GoRouter documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html),

> GoRouter can push a screen onto the Navigator's history stack using
> context.push(), and can pop the current screen via context.pop().
> However, imperative navigation is known to cause issues with the
> browser history.

So, on the web, we have to use `.go()`. Then, if we want to be able to go back with both the browser and in-app back buttons it's nice to call `window.history.back();`.

But that doesn't work on native mobile apps. So on apps, we have to use `Navigator.of(context).maybePop();`. But... that doesn't work if using `.go()` to navigate through the app, because it just closes the app.

So does that mean we should navigate with `.go()` on the web and `.push()` on mobile apps? Is there any other solution?

I tried looking for a solution on [the official GoRouter documentation page](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/l) and also on [GoRouter's GitHub issue page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+goRouter+back), but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate on the web, use `context.go()` and enable browser history by use `window.history.back()`. When it comes to mobile apps, user `Navigator.of(context).push()` for navigation. It is recommended to selectively choose the suitable method based on the platform using kIsWeb from dart:io.

Please check below code:

```
if (kIsWeb) {
    context.go('/your_screen');
    window.history.back();
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => YourScreen(),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Although agree on doing that, did you find that solution in any official documentation? It's like GoFlutter doesn't explicitly say this is the way to do it, right?